# cursor will not activate to allow input in text box

Tags: html, css

I am using CSS and html5 to create website.  I have a form with 3 text boxes as input.     I surround the form with a div tag and each of the 3 text boxes with div tags for positioning.  I am not able to enter text in my text boxes after the text boxes are positioned.  What is wrong?

```
Here is the HTML used:

<div id = "textboxsection">
<form method= "post" action= "pdonameinsert.php" >

<!--First name.-->
<div id = "firstnametextbox">
First Name: <input type="text" name ="firstname" placeholder = "First Name">
</div><br><br>

<!--Middle name.-->
<div id = "middlenametextbox">
Middle Initial: <input type="text" name ="middleinitial" placeholder = "Middle Initial"><br>
</div><br>

<!--Last name.-->
<div id = "lastnametextbox"></div>
Last Name: <input type="text" name = "lastname" placeholder = "Last Name"><br>
<br>

</div>
```

Here is the CSS used

```
#textboxsection
{
   position:relative;
   top:3px;
   left:160px;
}
```

Here the CSS code is used for each text box input.  The positioning is different.

```
#firstnametextbox
{
   position:relative;
   top:0px;
   left:5px;
   width:500px;
   height:10px;
}
```

Comment: You must have more than this going on, because this works: http://jsfiddle.net/cUv28/  Do you have something else positioned over these elements?

Comment: @Barbara Laird.  I have another div tag surround the form to place and position a colored background.

Comment: I got rid of that.  It works.  Now how can I had a background color and allow text entry?  haha.

Comment: There is no reason another div wrapped around that form shouldn't work.  But, is there a reason you're not adding the background color to the texboxsection div?  Also, note your extra </div> after lastnametextbox.  Maybe it's unmatched tags that is causing you problems.

Comment: @Barbara  I checked the div tags. They match.

Comment: In your questions's code they don't.  The form isn't ended before the </div> for textboxsection occurs.  And first name and middle name are wrapped in a div, where last name has a div defined above it.

Comment: @Barbara  I just removed all the position properties from the CSS file.  It works.  Why does CSS do that?  hmmm.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index

Comment: rjpedrosa provided a solution Barbara.  I will read the mozilla article.  Thank you.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a functional example: [jsfiddle.net/cUv28/3](http://jsfiddle.net/cUv28/3)

HTML:

```
<form id="textboxsection" method="post" action="pdonameinsert.php">
    <!--First name.-->
    First Name:
    <input id="firstnametextbox" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
    <!--Middle name.-->
    Middle Initial:
    <input id="middlenametextbox" type="text" name="middleinitial" placeholder="Middle Initial">
    <!--Last name.-->
    Last Name:
    <input id="lastnametextbox" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
 </form>
```

CSS:

```
#textboxsection {
position:relative;
top:3px;
left:160px;
padding:10px;
background-color:#F00;
}
#firstnametextbox {
position:relative;
top:0px;
left:5px;
width:500px;
height:10px;
}
```